# Is tag listing by popularity broken?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I went to the [last page of tags by popularity](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1081&tab=popular). But all of them are in the range of W to Z, which seems rather alphabetical. Also [xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsl) is probably not the least popular tag with 17000 questions.

Is it broken at the moment?

[image: List of popular tags]

Comment: These are synonyms; `xsl` is a synonym for `xslt`. It has 0 questions attached to it *directly*. Same for `zc.buildout`, a synonym for `buildout`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Should we have a feature request that those are either removed from the list or sorted acoording their associated/indirect questions?

Comment: I personally don't see much point; there are already other pages to discover and handle tag synonyms (click the 'tag synonyms' link in your screenshot). I still would want them to be discoverable and showing in a tag search on that page, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at tag synonyms and suggested tag synonyms; these all have 0 questions attached to them so are sorted at the end of the list when sorting by popularity.

When you mouse-over these, the popup shows stats and information for the target tag, the tag these tags are a synonym of. So [xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsl) is a synonym of [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt), [zc.buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zc.buildout) is a (suggested) synonym of [buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buildout), etc.

The tags are sorted by popularity, then by name, so tags with equal popularity are listed alphabetically. The tag synonyms are all listed last, from about [page 1029 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1029&tab=popular), so over 50 pages of them.